# Reading Nexus s Ndef Message on my desktop using ACR122

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s, ndef

I have developed an Android activity that pushes NDEF message like in android [sample document](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/nfc/ForegroundNdefPush.html)

On my Desktop I have ACR122 reader connected to it which I was able to read/write regular NFC tags using its SDK, but I cant get to read the mobile NDEF message, how can I read it?

Comment: Derawi Biometrics and Heiko Witte have a solution for this. Look at http://biometrics.derawi.com/?p=222 or http://hwit.bitstacks.com/2011/08/31/nfc-with-the-nexus-s-and-acr122-reader/

Comment: Hi i have found this project and it works well
http://code.google.com/p/ismb-npp-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NDEF message is pushed using the peer-to-peer (p2p) mode of NFC. On top of P2P, the LLCP (Logical Link Control Protocol) is used, and on top of that Google has implemented the NDEF push protocol. The latter you can find [here](http://source.android.com/compatibility/ndef-push-protocol.pdf).

I think the the ACR122 supports at least P2P. But I'm not sure whether it supports LLCP; if it does, then you will still need to implement a client for Google's NDEF push protocol on top of that to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

The ACR122 is okay for R/W mode, but SDK does not support LLCP based P2P. You have to use the open-source solutions like nfclib or ismb.

Regards,
Petr